# Problemas de conexión MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Quiero conectar un servidor ubicado en Internet a una base de datos MySQL corriendo en un servidor de red local pero que tiene asignada una IP pública .. por tanto a todos los efectos es también un servidor en Internet.

Tengo un conector típico:

```
$mymymy = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME, DB_PORT);
if ($mymymy->connect_errno) {
echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: (" . $mymymy->connect_errno . ") " . $mymymy->connect_error;
}
```

La especificación del puerto es debido a que el puerto de escucha del servidor en la red local para MySQL es distinto del tradicional 3306

El asunto es que cuando coloco los parámetros de configuración de conexión en un cliente MySQL en mi PC o incluso en un dispositivo movil (Android) se conecta perfectamente y visualizo las tablas de la Db a través de Internet, sin embargo cuando coloco exactamente este mismo script en un servidor web de Internet .. este no logra conectarse .. y son exactamente los mismos parámetros

Comment: el usuario con el que te conectas tiene permisos para conectarse desde otro servidor?

Comment: Ignoro si tiene tales permisos, de hecho no sabía que fueran necesarios permisos adicionales para establecer la conexión desde otro servidor, la conexión tiene lugar correctamente desde un cliente de PC (El que trae incorporado PHPStorm) y desde otro cliente desde Android en un móvil ... puedes darme más detalles de que permisos hay que darle al servidor para que acepte conexiones desde otro servidor?

Comment: ¿Tienes abierto el puerto para que sea accesible desde fuera de la máquina?

Comment: Puede que tu consulta este relacionada con este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380797/enable-remote-mysql-connection-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user).

Comment: ¿Exactamente qué mensaje de error obtienes al conectarte? Si es tiempo de conexión agotado (o connection timeout similares) se debe a que tu proveedor tiene un cortafuegos que impide conexiones salientes, en general o permitiendo únicamente puertos seguros (80, 443, etc). Deberás contactar con soporte de tu alojamiento para preguntarles acerca de esta situación.

Comment: El puerto está abierto, sólo que no es un puerto común .. pero funciona perfectamente con clientes MySQL que he probado, sólo no lo hace cuando he intentado hacer la conexión desde un servidor web ... el error que dá es el 2003. y estos son los valores que devuelve:  `"client_version" => 50639
 "connect_errno"  => 2003
 "connect_error"  => "Can't connect to MySQL server on '###.###.###.###' (110)` , Todos los demás valores los devuelve NULL

Answer (score 1):

1. Hay que revisar 4 cosas la primera es que el usuario tenga los
   permisos para conectarse de forma remota.
2. EL servidor debe tener habilitado la escucha el el puerto que le
   solicitas.
3. La instancia de la base de datos debe tener habilitada la opcion
   de conexión remota
4. Podrías revisar el `log.error` del servidor para tener una idea de
   porque rechaza la conexión.

Answer (score -1):

Cuando desarrollo código relacionado con páginas o aplicaciones web, siempre utilizo máquinas virtuales con una configuración exactamente igual que la que tendrá el servidor donde dicha página será alojada. Por otra parte, casi en todos los casos necesito acceso a bases de datos que se encuentren dentro de la máquina virtual, pero MySQL no está configurado por defecto para permitir conexiones remotas. Debido a esto, hay que modificar algunos parámetros de configuración de MySQL, así como dar permisos a un determinado usuario para que pueda acceder.

**Paso 1**

Modificar el archivo de configuración de MySQL:

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Buscaremos las siguientes líneas y se descomentarán en caso de estar comentadas:

- skip-external-locking
- bind-address = 127.0.0.1

La IP que le vamos a dar a bind-address será 0.0.0.0. En caso de que tengáis una IP específica a la que queráis dar acceso, simplemente ponedla.

**Paso 2**

En este paso se reiniciará el servicio de MySQL para que se apliquen los cambios:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

**Paso 3**

Hay que dar permisos específicos de acceso al usuario de la base de datos. Yo para desarrollo siempre utilizo usuario root y contraseña root, pero cada uno que ponga el suyo. Antes de nada, hay que entrar a la consola de MySQL:

```
mysql –u root -p
```

Tras esto, se le dan los privilegios al usuario en cuestión. En este caso root:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Gracias a estos sencillos pasos, ya tendremos acceso remoto a la base de datos de un servidor o máquina virtual en la que estemos desarrollando. ¡Saludos!

Espero te solucione el problema.
la info https://geekytheory.com/como-permitir-el-acceso-remoto-a-una-base-de-datos-mysql

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php 

function conectar(){

  /*Sirve para los acentos y las ñ tildes de mi web*/
  //header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');

  try {
    $conexion = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DBNAME)or die("Error en conexion a la base de datos");        
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Atrapada la Excepción Predeterminada\n", $e;
  }                           

  return $conexion;
}

function desconectar($conexion){
  mysqli_close($conexion);
}

?>
```

Comment: Este no es el caso toda la DB está hecha en UTF8 .. pero aun así al momento de cargar el objeto mysqli le declaro:  $mysqli->set_charset("utf8"); para que todo vaya en la misma cuerda .. el asunto es el establecimiento como tal de la conexión ... simplemente desde un servidor web **No se conecta** y si lo hace desde clientes MySQL de PC y de Android

Comment: Esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por su contenido (las publicaciones que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad). Por favor, edita tu respuesta para añadir una descripción de cómo este código resolvería el problema. Lee [answer] para más información.